# Extract WebTable using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, html-table

I would like to extract a specific table from https://nepsealpha.com/ which contains many tables. Picture showing the required table. Changing table index do not show the required table using below code. Index can change from 0 to 12 but required table not showing. Help me. [Required Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDFuM.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Users/Personal/WebDriver/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
accept_untrusted_certs = True

driver.get('https://nepsealpha.com/')
sleep(5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
df = pd.read_html(str(table),header=0)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

choose the table by its id which is unique

```
table  = soup.find(id="articlebody")
rows = table.tbody.findAll("tr")
for row in rows:
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    print cells
```

Comment: table  = soup.find(id="info-table0")
print(table) #results None. I am not getting Nischitha !

Comment: Iterate through the cells and print it as above

Comment: Dear Nischitha, Could you please test and paste working code for me. There are many tables but the table which i want to extract is not working as I thought. My  require table is as shown in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDFuM.png (in above as well).

Answer (score 0):

The table you need is loaded through JS. We would require to scroll the page for executing js so this works for me:-

```
driver.get('https://nepsealpha.com/')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
sleep(5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5')

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))
df_required = df[1]
```

Comment: Dear Prakhar, Thank you !! Exact as I expected using panda dataframe. But I would like to ask one more thing "Can I iterate as we do in other cases for the different pages in case of ("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);"), we can see multiple page 1,2,3,.. at bottom.while True:
            try:link=self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next")
                print('Moving Next Page')
                link.click().

Comment: changing xpath //*[@id="scoreBoard"]/div/div/div[2]/div/a[3],  //*[@id="scoreBoard"]/div/div/div[2]/div/a[4],  //*[@id="scoreBoard"]/div/div/div[2]/div/a[5] loads different table values in web, But our above method always extracts same value. I would like to get table iterating those xpath changes and combining table in those pages too.

Comment: This is not the original question. Please raise a separate question for this with the problem you are facing and what have you tried so far.